# Maximum Likelihood with penalization

Tags: maximum-likelihood, references, poisson-distribution, likelihood, regularization

Can someone please give me a reference where I can find more info on the method of Poisson maximum likelihood maximization with smoothing hyperparameters[image]

Here we want to find the parameters Ws and βs are called the smoothing hyperparameter. Does anybody know what's the name of this method?

Comment: This looks like a Poisson fused lasso style optimization setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are some book-length treatments of penalized likelihood theory, you could have a look at :

[Maximum Penalized Likelihood Estimation: Volume II: Regression](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387402675)   and  [Maximum Penalized Likelihood Estimation: Volume I: Density Estimation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387952683).