# Can stochastic gradient descent for Bayesian Inference?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, inference, stochastic-gradient-descent

I was looking at the Bayesian MAP estimate formula which is the "argmax(likelihood * prior)".

Can this be calculated using stochastic gradient descent? Gradient descent requires knowing the derivative. The derivative of the likelihood function is routinely calculated and I am guessing it should be possible to calculate the derivative of most prior distributions?

Thus, can stochastic gradient descent be used to calculate the argmax(prior * likelihood)?

Thanks!

Comment: Provided you can calculate the derivative of the  (log) likelihood and the (log) prior, yes, you can use this method. This question is basically a duplicate of your other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bayesian Estimation: MCMC vs MAP](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/545084/bayesian-estimation-mcmc-vs-map)